# How to get Gmaps.js to draw a route between dynamic markers javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

I'm using [Gmaps.js](https://github.com/hpneo/gmaps/blob/master/examples/routes.html) to display coordinates I'm pulling in from a database and I'm trying to connect all of the markers up together to make a route. But the only thing I can find is the code below.

How can I modify this to draw a route between the first and second markers and second and third and so on?

```
map.drawRoute({
  origin: [-12.044012922866312, -77.02470665341184],
  destination: [-12.090814532191756, -77.02271108990476],
  travelMode: 'driving',
  strokeColor: '#783bf2',
  strokeOpacity: 0.6,
  strokeWeight: 6
});
```

Here's what I've tried:

```
var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, longit);
bounds.push(latlng);

/* Add Marker */
map.addMarker({
  lat: lat,
  lng: longit,
  title: 'title',
});

$(latlng).each(function( index, element ) {
  map.drawRoute({
    origin: [lat, longit],
    destination: [lat + 1, lng + 1],
    travelMode: 'driving',
    strokeColor: '#131540',
    strokeOpacity: 0.6,
    strokeWeight: 6
  });
});
```

Comment: Seems like you will have to use `waypoints` like on the original API: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/intro

Comment: @alalp I tried that, but to no success.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one approach:

Create an array of coordinates:

```
var locations = [
  [30.465229, -97.759501],
  [30.459517, -97.754317],
  [30.452511, -97.750729],
  [30.444433, -97.742799],
  [30.436055, -97.734473],
  [30.429190, -97.722731]
];
```

Loop over the coordinates and draw the route between each pair:

```
for(var index = 0; index < locations.length; index++) {  
  if (index < locations.length - 1) {
    drawRoute(locations[index], locations[index + 1]);
  }
}

function drawRoute(origin, destination) {
  map.drawRoute({
    origin: origin,
    destination: destination,
    travelMode: 'driving'
  });
}
```

Take a look at [this JSBin](http://jsbin.com/ruyonoh/3/edit?js,output) for a working version of the above code.

Comment: Thanks!! was pulling my hair out over this.

Comment: No problem! Glad I could help :)